# How to get S.M.A.R.T. info from disks?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10.3-rio

I tried code found in Google but nothing works and in most cases it doesn't even compile (missing units, undeclared data types etc).
I finally found something that looks complete but shows "The handle is invalid" error:
http://rsdn.org/article/delphi/SMART.xml
You can download the file from here:
http://rsdn.org/article/delphi/smart/smart.zip

The problem is with function `function OpenSMART(DrvNum:Byte): THandle;`

```
hSMARTIOCTL:=CreateFile(PChar('\\.\PhysicalDrive'+inttostr(DrvNum)),GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE,nil,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);
result:= hSMARTIOCTL;
```

How can I fix it or where can I find working example?

I use Delphi 7 Pro and Delphi 10.3.

Comment: The link in your question to download the file does not works

Comment: It works for me. I archived it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20220131133145/http://rsdn.org/article/delphi/smart/smart.zip

Comment: Strange, it still does not works for me. But thank you for the archive, that link worked well

Comment: @GuidoG Does it compile fine? What OS you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it needs to be run as admin. Then it just works.

Comment: No, the Windows version is relevant, too. See the [documentation to `CreateFileA()`, chapter "Physical Disks and Volumes"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#physical-disks-and-volumes) - the article at most mentions _Windows XP_, for which administrative privileges were not needed. Execute it on XP.

Comment: @AmigoJack Under Windows 7 works great if you run as admin